# Change selectable dates in jQuery datepicker for different forms whilst keeping other options the same and DRY

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

All I am trying to do is keep my code for the datepicker DRY but I can't seem to get my changes to work. I have a general set of options that I want to retain across all datepickers:

```
var dateToday = new Date(); 
$(".selectdate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'd MM yy',
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true
});
```

But then one some datepickers I need the maxDate option and others I need the minDate option but I can't get it to work. For example:

```
$("#calldate").datepicker({
    maxDate: dateToday
});
```

So I have an input field with the id 'calldate' and class 'selectdate' and would have thought this would work but it doesn't - the calendar displays with all options set for $('.selectdate').... but the maxDate doesn't work. And what I don't want is to repeat code for every datepicker I have, like so:

```
$("#fromdate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'd MM yy',
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    minDate: dateToday
});

$("#calldate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'd MM yy',
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    maxDate: dateToday
});
```

I hope this makes sense and someone can help me sort, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.datepicker.setDefaults()` then override/add new options when you call `.datepicker()` on an element where you want more/different options to apply, like this:

```js
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    dateFormat: 'd MM yy',
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true
});

$('#fromdate').datepicker();
$('#calldate').datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<label>#calldate
  <input type="text" id="calldate" min='0'/>
</label>
<label>#fromdate
  <input type="text" id="fromdate"/>
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed and works a dream :)